# How to select element in jQuery if it is a var in document.getElementbyId?

Tags: jquery

Is this statement in jQuery right? If I do some javascript code and get the element as var will jQuery be able to select it?

```
var cd = document.getElementById("display_" + id); //this comes from a long code.
$(cd).click(function(){.....
```

**Edit:** I know that the alternative to this is

```
$('#' + cd.id).click(function(){.....
```

But just want to know if it works like the first statement. And I have tested it in Chrome and it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, That should work fine. you can wrap a dom element returned by `getElement...` inside `$()`

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you usually do `$("#display_" + id).click(function(){...});`

Comment: Usually, but consider existing application with a bunch of pure javascript - now jQuery is added and OP can't rewrite all js code on the fly. Just read: `//this comes from a long code.`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Oh, sorry, i tought that that phrase was referring only to the id variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your current code does works: [Fiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/DcU78/)

But, I did suggest not to make a extra call to `document.getElementById` and then again converting it to a jQuery object.

You can do this, if possible for you:

```
var cd = '#display_' + id;
$(cd).click(function(){
    alert('Button Clicked!');
});
```

[Fiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/DcU78/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Palash but the point is that I am blind to `id` or '#display'. I only have the `cd`.